# CSS Reset ou Normalize?

Tags: css, css3

Ouvi falar sobre o *CSS reset* e também tenho conhecimento do *Normalize CSS* que é um tipo de *reset* para que os navegadores renderizem CSS básico de maneira padronizada.

Procurando a melhor solução em CSS, me surgiu a dúvida: Qual utilizar?

Comment: Agradeço pelo seu tempo, Dorival! Mas fiquei com uma dúvida sobre o seu comentário: Se eu usar o normalize, e ele definir algumas características comuns a alguns dos meus elementos, e depois usar o reset, e ele resetar as características, não perde um pouco o sentido? Já que um está sobrescrevendo o outro? Desculpa se entendí errado mas foi isso que me pareceu.

Comment: O respeito da sobrescrita é o detalhe, nesse ponto geralmente são coisas minimas como tamanho da font dos "h"s ou um espaçamento de "input", que são sobrescritos, ele não vai sobrescrever por exemplo um "box-sizing" ou um "p line-height: 1em". Pra mim são coisas minimas que se forem algo que realmente te incomodem você pode retirar na lib do Normalize, mas, recomento que você use este.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo seu tempo e pelos seus ótimos comentários, @DorivalZanetto. Entendí e vou optar então por usar os 2. Novamente obrigado, me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O objetivo dos arquivos de reset para o `css` nada mais são do que, como o nome já diz, resetar o estilo padrão que alguns elementos possuem.

Por exemplo, os botões possuem um fundo cinza, as listas possuem as marcações nas laterais, os títulos possuem margens, tabelas possuem bordas, etc..

Tudo isso são estilos nativos dos elementos. Esses arquivos de reset irão "eliminar" esses estilos SOBRESCREVENDO com o `css` contido nesse `reset.css`.

Por exemplo:

```
button {
    border:none;
    background:transparent;
}
```

Este código `css` irá fazer com que os botões não tenham mais esse estilo.

#### Por que fazer isso?

O motivo de utilizar um `reset` seria para evitar que as propriedades padrões interfiram com o layout que VOCÊ está criando. Se você utilizar um botão próprio que possua cores vivas, etc.. Não vai ficar bacana com um botão cinza, ou não vai ter o mesmo tamanho. Então um dos motivos seria a melhoria visual.

Outro motivo, seria a melhoria ESTRUTURAL. Veja a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é uma tabela com o estilo padrão. Além do visual não ser atrativo, note que ela possui bordas indesejáveis, que irão atrapalhar na sua estrutura. Para remover essas bordas, nós usamos um `reset` para a tabela.

#### Qual usar?

Não existe um `reset` melhor que o outro, nem o mais correto a ser usado, nem restrição de usar somente um, somente outro, ou até mesmo de usar mais de um ao mesmo tempo. O que você deve fazer é analisar o que você precisa e quanto precisa 'limpar' do código padrão. Muitos deles irão criar um `css` para elementos que muitas vezes você nem irá usar.

Eu, particularmente, cheguei ao ponto de não usar nenhum reset pré-definido. Eu mesmo removo os estilos padrão dos elementos que utilizo e que preciso.

Para complementar sua leitura, achei esses links que me pareceram interessantes:

- http://www.pinceladasdaweb.com.br/blog/2008/11/10/10-tecnicas-para-reset-css/
- http://tableless.com.br/repensando-css-resets/
- http://www.devmedia.com.br/como-utilizar-a-tecnica-css-reset/26797

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, agora entendí exatamente a diferença e o que fazer!

Comment: Fico feliz em poder ajudar! Se tiver mais dúvidas, não hesite em questionar =D

Answer (score 3):

**Reset**

Um reset como o próprio nome diz irá resetar todas as configurações pré-definidas dos navegadores, desta forma você poderá definir o seu próprio css,sem utilizar as características  que cada navegador utiliza.

**Normalize**

Normalize  como o próprio nome diz irá normalizar, isto é, ele tentará deixar os estilos padronizados em todos os navegadores.

Portanto se você deseja definir o seu próprio `css` sem interferência das regras definidas pelo navegador utilize `reset` , se você quer começar por base em algo que já possui alta compatibilidade nos navegadores
     e acrescentar as suas regras  `Normalize` será melhor.

Deixo uma literatura complementar sobre o assunto:

[CSS: reset or normalize?](https://the-pastry-box-project.net/oli-studholme/2013-june-3)

[Forget normalize or resets; lay your own CSS foundation](http://jaydenseric.com/blog/forget-normalize-or-resets-lay-your-own-css-foundation)

Comment: Sendo assim não tem lógica eu usar os 2, certo?

Comment: @TiagoP.C 
Exatamente, se você utilizar os dois estará sobrescrevendo algumas regras,  o reset limpa tudo. o Normalize analisa todas as  regras boas e as mantem e substitui as ruins pelas boas, neste caso digo boas como as mais compativeis nos navegadores.

Comment: Entendí, decidí que vou fazer meu próprio reset, se der certo manterei, caso venha a ter problemas com diferentes navegadores opto pelo Normalize. Muito obrigado @Gabriel Rodrigues pela resposta, foi muito útil!

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues, descordo no ponto de que "se você utilizar os dois estará sobrescrevendo algumas regras" isso não é uma regra, veja bem, se precisarmos realmente que todos os elementos de formulários sejam padronizados, por mais que seja elaborado um bom Reset, tenho certeza que este, jamais será tão bom quanto o Normalize por exemplo, pois este segundo é feito baseado não apenas nos navegadores mais conhecidos mais em uma serie deles, alguns que talvez nem conhecemos. Já se eu precisar de um *{margin: 0}, o Normalize não tem por default, então preciso colocar em um Reset.

Comment: Note agora, que são duas coisas que podem sim ser usadas em conjuntos, e altamente recomendáveis por grandes dev. front como o "csswizardry" na documentação do ITCSS, sendo que a questão de sobrescrita não é uma regra, como já disse e as vezes é necessário utilizar ambos para facilidade de organização e bons padrões de dev. sendo que não aconselho alterar lib de terceiros e essas muitas vezes não atendem todas as nossas necessidades. Por isso aconselho utilizar os dois e dei -1.

Comment: @DorivalZanetto seria interessante criar uma resposta com estes conceitos. pela minha experiência vejo que o uso de ambos em um projeto não seja necessário,  talvez você possa expor o contrario em uma resposta, obrigado pelo feedback li um pouco sobre ITCSS achei bem interessante.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues, agradeço pelo feed, porém não tenho interesse em elaborar mais uma resposta, considerando que já expressei a ideia para o autor da pergunta e que essa questão já possui duas respostas boas... Os comentários são mais para intuito de explicar o porque do meu Downvote, sendo que não acho justo apenas votar sem apresentar argumentos.