# CSS reset é sempre o mesmo?

Tags: html, css, front-end

O CSS Reset é sempre o mesmo, ou há outros que embora mantenham um mesmo padrão possuem características específicas a mais? É regra todos os CSS Reset serem iguais, isto é, se eu criar o meu com o que já é esperado e incrementar com algo a mais estaria errado?

Comment: Não é o mesmo e a forma como o *reset* é feito deve depender do projeto. Não tem porque inserir um arquivo *.css* cheio de regras só porque algum blog recomenda e chama isso de "boas práticas". Se `big, dfn, applet, object, etc` não existem na minha página, não tem porque estarem no meu css. :)

Comment: Relacionado, recomendo leitura: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100044/css-reset-ou-normalize/

Answer (score 6):

Existem vários tipos de **Reset** para **Css**. O mais conhecido e utilizado pelos desenvolvedores é o *Generic Reset CSS*

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

Um outro conhecido e muito utilizado também é o modelo proposto por [**Eric Meyer**](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/)

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Dentre outros, como mostra uma uma postagem com as [10 Técnicas para Reset CSS](http://www.pinceladasdaweb.com.br/blog/2008/11/10/10-tecnicas-para-reset-css/).

Enfim, respondendo a sua pergunta objetivamente. Não é regra utilizar um tipo de Reset Css, você pode utilizar os modelos existentes, ou criar um de acordo com suas necessidades específicas.

Comment: A iniciativa é interessante, só sugiro uma atualizada, pois a informação mais recente das mencionadas é de 2008. O próprio meyer atualizou o reset em 2011, com alguns elementos de HTML5 - o que você postou é o de 2007.

Comment: @Bacco Editei a resposta para o reset de 2011 proposto pelo Meyer conforme citou, obrigado.