# Por que "html, body" e não apenas "body" para eliminar as margens da página?

Tags: html, css, front-end

Quando se quer eliminar as margens-padrão da página sempre vejo o seguinte código CSS:

```
html, body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Por que usar `html, body` se usando apenas `body` que é o *corpo* da página já resolve?

Exemplo:

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Nenhuma margem ou espaçamento
</div>
```

Existe alguma razão técnica para incluir o `html` no código?

Comment: Talvez nos navegadores mais antigos, havia essa necessidade de identificar toda a hierarquia do html, eu sempre declaro somente *body* e nunca tive problema. Acho que isso é a mesma coisa de ver alguns textos escritos por pessoas mais antigas usando "eh" ao invés de "é".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percebi que o uso de ambos elementos `html, body` na declaração do CSS só é necessário ao usar alguns estilos. No caso do `margin`, o `html` se torna desnecessário porque apenas o elemento `body` possui a *margem padrão*.

Geralmente usa-se `html, body` para outros estilos quando o estilo que se quer aplicar ao `body` depende também do estilo do `html`.

Um exemplo clássico é o estilo `height`. Por padrão, tanto o `html` quanto o `body` não possuem altura pré-definida. A altura de ambos dependerá do conteúdo da página, ou seja, a altura de ambos será até o final do último elemento da página.

Logo, se eu definir `height` apenas no `body`, não terá efeito porque a altura do `html` não foi definida. A altura do *elemento-filho* se baseia na altura do *elemento-pai*. Se o `html`, que é *pai* do `body`, não possui altura, logo o `body` fica sem referência.

Portanto, setando a altura em ambos:

```
html, body{
   height: 100%;
}
```

O `body` terá a altura do `html`, que será a mesma do *viewport* (área vísivel da janela).

Resumindo, se quiser apenas retirar as margens da página, use apenas `body`.

Comment: Uma alternativa para setar a altura sem precisar mexer no estilo da tag `html`, apenas na `body` é usar `height: 100vh;`

Answer (score 7):

A razão para isso, é devido os navegadores utilizarem diferentes folhas de estilos padrão.

Exemplo, o *Chrome* pode utilizar um padrão de `margins` para o documento *HTML*:

```
/* É apenas um exemplo */
html {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

O *Firefox*:

```
/* É apenas um exemplo */
html {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

E o *IE*:

```
/* É apenas um exemplo */
html {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Se você não redefinir o estilo padrão, provavelmente terá algum problema. Por isso é recomendado redefinir todo o estilo padrão.

Claro que hoje em dia creio (não digo impossível) haja algum navegador que utilize `margin` ou `padding` padrão no documento *HTML*.

Comment: @dvd mas existem diversos navegadores disponíveis, não só os "mais conhecidos" e cada um pode utilizar um default. Na dúvida, sempre bom previnir :P

Answer (score 3):

Como dito pelos colegas cada Browser tem sua *folha de estilo* padrão (usre-agent css). Aqui vc pode ler sobre isso [O que é User Agent StyleSheets?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165937/o-que-%C3%A9-user-agent-stylesheets)

Outro ponto que vc pode verificar isso é no quesito *crossbrowser*, onde cada motor de renderização tem suas particularidades e é preciso usar o **"Vendor Prefix"** para as classes funcionarem em cada browser diferente, vc pode ler sobre isso aqui [É necessário adicionar prefixos em algumas propriedades do CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3674/%C3%89-necess%C3%A1rio-adicionar-prefixos-em-algumas-propriedades-do-css/3683#3683)

Inclusive é devido a essa diferença de CSS dos user-agentes que que exitem "metodologias" como u **CSS.Normalize** *(tenta deixar todos os Browsers com o mesmo aspecto visual)* e o **CSS Reset** *(remove valores default de todos as classe)*, vc pode ler sobre isso aqui: [CSS Reset ou Normalize?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100044/css-reset-ou-normalize)

**Projeto CSS.Normalize:** http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-normalize-css/ (palavras do criador)

**OBS:** Repare que essa opção usa volares diferentes para HTML e Body

```
html {
  line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

**CSS Reset:** https://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/ (existem vários outros)

**OBS:** Repare que esse cara "zera" valores para quase tudo rss

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

E aqui tem uma lista dos valores Default do CSS sugeridos pela W3C: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

```
html, address,
blockquote,
body, dd, div,
dl, dt, fieldset, form,
frame, frameset,
h1, h2, h3, h4,
h5, h6, noframes,
ol, p, ul, center,
dir, hr, menu, pre   { 
    display: block; unicode-bidi: embed 
}
```

**Aqui tem uma lista dos valores default do CSS para a maioria dos elementos** https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

---

Apenas uma imagem de referência sobre a tag `<h1>` No Chrome e no FF Quantum. Repare que mesmo sem colocar um CSS o próprio Browser tem sua folha de estilo default. E isso pode variar de Browser para Browser conforme dito acima...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]