# Como tirar o o espaço em branco nesse html

Tags: html, css

[image: ![Como tirar esse cabeçalho em branco]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt9es.png)

Ja tentei colocar height:100% mas nada mudou

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/css/frontend/ficha_emergencia.css') }}" />
</head>
<body class="body" style="border:0; margin: 6;">
    <table class="onu firstPage" width="100%" height="100%" border="0">
        <tr class="title">
            <td colspan="3">FICHA DE EMERGÊNCIA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="33%">
                <div class="line">
                    <span class="label">Importador/Expedidor:</span>
                </div>
                <div class="line">
                    <span class="label">Endereço:</span>
                </div>
                <div class="line">
                    <span class="label">Telefone:</span>
                </div>
                <div class="line">
                    <span class="label">Telefone de Emergência:</span>
                 <br></br><br></br>
                 </div>
            </td>
```

Segue o Css

```
    body, .body
{
  font-family: Roboto;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  text-align: justify;
  /*width: 780px;*/
}

.firstPage
{
  border-left: 30px solid red;
  border-right: 30px solid red;
}

td
{
    font-size: 7pt;
    /* vertical-align: top; */
    height: normal;
}

.title
{
  font-size: 8pt;
  text-align: center;
}

.label
{
  font-size: 7pt;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/*td
{

}*/
.border td
{
  height:9pt;
  border-top: 1.4px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1.4px solid black;
}
.borda td
{
  border-top:1.4px solid black;
}

.group
{
  font-size: 9pt;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Qual espaço você se refere?

Comment: O do cabeçalho a imagem assim não revela direito, tem que clicar nela para ver,

Comment: onde está o css?

Comment: Jovem tenta explicar melhor seu problema, mesmo com a imagem não está claro de entender o que vc quer

Comment: Tem um espaço em branco no cabeçalho que não consigo tirar.

Comment: Na real eu quero que o html fique sem margem que encoste na parte de cima, já tentei colocar margin-top:0px;

Comment: tenta colocar uma borda nos elementos para você visualizar melhor o que esta acontecendo. Obs.: talvez o css vertical-align seja a solução

Comment: vc tem um style no body que da uma margem de 6, retire ele

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/275368/por-que-html-body-e-n%C3%A3o-apenas-body-para-eliminar-as-margens-da-p%C3%A1gina

Answer (score 0):

Pus o seu mesmo código em um snippet e removi a margin, a princípio está sem o espaço acima ao qual você mencionou.

```css
body,
.body {
  font-family: Roboto;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  text-align: justify;
  /*width: 780px;*/
}

.firstPage {
  border-left: 30px solid red;
  border-right: 30px solid red;
}

td {
  font-size: 7pt;
  /* vertical-align: top; */
  height: normal;
}

.title {
  font-size: 8pt;
  text-align: center;
}

.label {
  font-size: 7pt;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*td
    {

    }*/

.border td {
  height: 9pt;
  border-top: 1.4px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1.4px solid black;
}

.borda td {
  border-top: 1.4px solid black;
}

.group {
  font-size: 9pt;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/css/frontend/ficha_emergencia.css') }}" />
</head>

<body class="body" style="border:0;">
  <table class="onu firstPage" width="100%" height="100%" border="0">
    <tr class="title">
      <td colspan="3">FICHA DE EMERGÊNCIA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="33%">
        <div class="line">
          <span class="label">Importador/Expedidor:</span>
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <span class="label">Endereço:</span>
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <span class="label">Telefone:</span>
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <span class="label">Telefone de Emergência:</span>
          <br><br><br><br>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pois é, aqui não funcionou, não sei bem se é um bug

Comment: você poderia colocar o código completo no codepen? ou em alguma plataforma do tipo, assim podemos analizar melhor...

Comment: Como eu faria isso?
E o código tem trechos que ele busca de um banco mysql, mas faço sim

Comment: poste apenas o html e o css, use [esta plataforma](https://codepen.io/) por exemplo, coloque seu código e edite sua pergunta colocando o link :D

Comment: https://codepen.io/JalisDiehl/pen/qJpwZz
Consegue ver?

Comment: @JalisLucianDiehl com qual navegador está aparecendo este espaço?

Comment: Google chrome..

Answer (score -1):

altere a linha:

```
<body class="body" style="border:0; margin: 6;">
```

Para:

```
<body class="body" style="border:0; margin: 0;">
```

Comment: Esse margin é horizontal, para afastar aquelas bordas vermelhas dos lados

Comment: Não! border e margin são para margens e bordas horizontais E verticais.