# Espaço entre tags HTML

Tags: html, css

sou iniciante no desenvolvimento com HTML e CSS, e estou tendo dificuldade em entender o porque que entre as tags html fica um espaço. Como no exemplo a seguir onde tenho um header, uma div e um footer com cores diferentes para facilitar a visualização, e entre eles fica sempre um linha branca. Nesse casos eu teria que trabalhar com margin negativa para corrigir isso ?

```css
body{
margin: 0;
}

header {
background-color: #333333;
color: white;
}

div {
background-color: red;  
}
  
footer {
background-color: #000000;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<header class="top-header">
<h1>Header</h1> 
</header>
 
<div class="top-content">
<h1>Main Content</h1>
</div>
 
<footer>
<h1>Teste</h1>
</footer>
```

Comment: Isso acontece pois os navegadores utilizam valores padrão em cada elemento. Pressione `F12` e inspecione o elemento `H1`. Verás que ele já está com alguns valores predefinidos. Para contornar isso você pode usar a técnica de [**CSS Reset ou Normalize**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100044/99718)

Comment: Como já comentado, os navegadores possuem alguns valores padrões, assim como a tag `body` o `h1` também possui uma margem padrão. Para retirar ela basta definir `margin: 0;` assim como fez no `body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É como o Valdeir falou no comentário. Vários elementos do HTML tem valores defauld de CSS que pode inclusive variar de Browser para Browser, por isso elementos como radio buttons, input, e selects são diferentes entre FireFox, Safari ou Chrome.

Caso te interesse aqui tem uma lista completa de todos os elementos HTML e dos seus valores *default* https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

No caso do H1 no Chreme por exemplo, o `user-agent`(estilo padrão do navegador) coloca no elemento os seguinte valores

```
h1 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Se vc inspecionar o `H1` vai ver que ele fica assim. A cor laranja é a margem que o elemento tem por padrão

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Exemplo de aplicação

Se vc tirar as margens do `H1` vai ver que as `divs` ficam coladas como vc quer.

```css
body{
margin: 0;
}

header {
background-color: #333333;
color: white;
}

div {
background-color: red;  
}
        
footer {
background-color: #000000;
color: white;
}
/* romeve as margens do h1*/
h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="top-header">
  <h1>Header</h1> 
</header>
    
<div class="top-content">
  <h1>Main Content</h1>
</div>
    
<footer>
  <h1>Teste</h1>
</footer>
```

**DICA:** Faça um teste rápido, pegue o código acima e onde for `<h1>` coloque `<p>` e veja que os espaços em branco vão voltar. Isso acontece pq assim como o `h1` a tag `p` também tem margens por *default*