# Flexbox deixando espaçamento vazio

Tags: css, flexbox

Estou estudando flexbox e decidi criar um menu, tudo funciona bem, mas esta ficando com um espaçamento sem eu ter dado, pelo que sei o flex: 1 ocupa todo o espaço, mas não é isso que esta ocorrendo.

Foto do problema:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Código: HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

> Código: CSS

```
.nav {

  background: #ED4343;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;

}
.nav-item {

  flex: 1;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;

}

a {

  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rapaz seu problema é que por default todo elemento `<ul>` tem um `padding`! Vc precisa remover esse `padding` do *user-agent* na mão, colocando `padding:0` na `ul` de classe `.nav`

Veja como fica o resultado:

```css
.nav {
 background: #ED4343;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
}

.nav-item {
 flex: 1;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
}

a {
 display: block;
 padding: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
 <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
 <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
 <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
 <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
 <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

Veja que na documentação oficial da **W3C** o `UL` tem os seguintes atributos por padrão!

```
ul {
display: block;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-before: 1em;
margin-after: 1em;
margin-start: 0;
margin-end: 0;
padding-start: 40px; 
}
```

***Fonte:*** https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/ul.html#ul-display

Para limpar esses estilos padrão que o user-agente coloca em alguns elementos vc pode usar um `Normalizer` ou fazer um `Reset` no CSS, essa resposta tem mais detalhes: [CSS Reset ou Normalize?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100044/css-reset-ou-normalize)

E sobre o que é o `user-agente` vc pode ler aqui: [O que é User Agent StyleSheets?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165937/o-que-%C3%A9-user-agent-stylesheets)

Comment: Deu certinho, eu fiquei um pouco surpreso em saber que por default o ul tem um padding, isso porque eu sempre criei menus usando o float e não dava esse espaçamento, mas obrigado, essa informação é bem útil

Comment: @PedroSilva da uma olhada nesse link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165937/o-que-%C3%A9-user-agent-stylesheets vc vai ver que por padrão o Browser pode estabelecer alguns CSS basa para a folha de estilo, podem ser ou não diferentes dos sugeridos pela W3C... por isso existem alguns normalizer.css e reset.css para tentar zerar ou igualar o css defaut de todos os browser

Comment: @PedroSilva outro link que vai te interessa a entender melhor o que aconteceu. São leituras que vão te servir pro resto da vida de dev. vale a pena parar um minutinho para ler https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100044/css-reset-ou-normalize