# IOS não aplica CSS

Tags: css

Este meu formulário não está funcionado no IOS, porém no Android fica perfeito.

No IOS é como se não tivesse sido aplicado nenhum estilo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
form.frm-captura{
    width: 100%;
}
input.frmbtncapt{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #FC613E; 
    color: #fff;
    border-width: 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #50636b;
}
input.frminput{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #FC613E;
    margin: 2px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ccc;
}

<form action="dados" method="post" class="frm-captura" name="frmcapt">
<input type="text" class="frminput" value="" name="emailcapt" placeholder="Insira seu email aqui!" required="required">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $painel_noticias[0]; ?>" name="escondido">
<input type="submit" class="frmbtncapt" name="btnsub" value="BAIXAR O EBOOK AGORA!">
</form>
```

Comment: Eu também tenho diversos problemas no IOS as vezes, eles parecem um IE da vida, um pouco melhorado.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Verdade, alguns CSS funcionam perfeitamente, outros nada, como se não tivesse sido aplicado estilo algum.

Comment: Onde é `background-color` coloque apenas `background`, e na propriedade `box-sizing` tb coloque com prefixo `-webkit-box-sizing` e faz um teste ai pra ver se melhora. Se resolver me fala que dou uma resposta com mais detalhes

Comment: @hugocsl sim, ele colocou a borda e uma cor de fundo, distante a cor, mas foi. Só que a formatação está longe do código.

Comment: @hugocsl não entendo, só com o formulário que está acontecendo isso, todo o restante do site fora formulário funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Nessa classe `input.frminput {` e nessa classe `input.frmbtncapt {` Coloca como primeiro atributo `all: unset;` tipo assim: `input.frmbtncapt { all: unset; ... resto das propriedade ... ` Testa colocando isso ai e me fala, se deu certo, depois vc pode testar tb colocando `!important`... mas primeiro testa com o `all: unset;` isso deve remover as classes padrão do `user-agent` do iOS, ("deve", pois não tenho um ambiente de teste aqui para confirmar isso)

Comment: @hugocsl Desculpe a demora, funcionou perfeitamente! Muito Obrigado...

Comment: Gladison vc se incomoda se eu colocar o meu comentário como resposta? Assim vc pode marcar a resposta e fechar a pergunta já que ela está resolvida. Pode ser? Ai posso dar mais detalhes e explicações para quem cair na sua pergunta procurando uma resposta etc

Comment: @hugocsl Faça isso, será um prazer.

Comment: Valeu Gladison, transformei o comentário e resposta e dei mais uma série de detalhes caso vc interesse em se aprofundar um pouco nas coisas ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o assunto foi resolvido no comentário, vou postar aqui o registro como resposta.

O que provavelmente acontece é que o `user-agent` do iOS colocas alguns estilos por *default* no elementos. Então mesmo vc não declarando uma propriedade ou outra no elemento é possível que o próprio iOS esteja colocando esses estilos. Vc pode ler mais sobre `user-agent` nessa pergunta. [O que é User Agent StyleSheets?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165937/o-que-%C3%A9-user-agent-stylesheets/165942)

É por isso também que algumas pessoas gostam de usar um `normalizer.css`, ou `reboot.css` como o próprio Bootstrap faz para tentar remover os estilos do `user-agent` e deixar todos os navegadores com um CSS mais homogênico entre eles. Vc pode ler um pouco sobre isso nessa questão: [CSS Reset ou Normalize?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100044/css-reset-ou-normalize)

---

**Agora o *workaroud* que solucionou o problema da questão.**

Primeiro colocar o que precisar com o prefixo `-webkit-` pois esse é o *vendor* *prefix* do iOS e Safari/Chrome

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
```

Segundo, evite propriedades long-hand, de preferencia por short-hand, pois alguma propriedade pode sobrescrever a outro, por exemplo, se vc tiver a estrutura como abaixo o estilo que fica valendo é o `background-image: linear-gradient` setado pelo `user-agent` e não a sua cor de `background-color`

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #000 100%); /* estilo user-agent */
background-color: #FC613E; /* seu estilo */
```

No entanto se vc colocar apenas `background:` vc vai indicar que todas as outras propriedades do background vão ficar como `initial`. Essa opção abaixo tem mais chance de prevalecer sobre o estilo do `user-agent`.

```
background: #FC613E; /* seu estilo */
```

Agora para tentar garantir que vc está removendo todas as propriedades do elemento e sobrescrever com a sua vc pode setar um all: unset; tipo assim: input.frmbtncapt { all: unset; ... resto das propriedade ... Dessa forma vc deve remover todos os estilos do `user-agent`. Vc pode ler mais sobre essa propriedade aqui: [Propriedade all no CSS. Para que serve e como funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/335015/propriedade-all-no-css-para-que-serve-e-como-funciona)

Um exemplo de organização das propriedade para garantir que vão funcionar no iOS seria assim: *(mas como disse vc ainda pode usar um `normalizer.css` ou `reset.css`)*

```
input.frmbtncapt{

  all:unset; /* remove estilos setados pelo user-agent */

  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  border-width: 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #50636b;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* coloca o prefixo do browser do iOS */
        box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #FC613E; /* usa a propriedade em short hand */
}
```